# Access a member of an object internal table line

Tags: attributes, abap

How can I access directly the attribute `DATA` of one object in the internal table `CHILDREN`?

```
CLASS class1 DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA: data TYPE string.
    DATA: children TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF REF TO class1 WITH EMPTY KEY.
    METHODS constructor
      IMPORTING data TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS class1 IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD constructor.
    me->data = data.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA children TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF REF TO class1.
  APPEND NEW #( data = 'test' ) TO children.
  WRITE children[ 1 ]->data.                      " <== syntax error
```

But I receive the syntax error message:

> Unexpected operator "->".

Answer (score 3):

[Table expressions (`children[ ... ]`) are allowed since ABAP 7.40 SP 02](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abennews-740-itab.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_1@1@) but the [object component selector `->` after a table expression is allowed only from ABAP 7.50](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abennews-750-expressions.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_4@4@) :

> From Release 7.50, the object component selector -> can be specified directly after table expressions that return a reference variable. This makes it possible to access components of the referenced object. An exception are table expressions whose result is determined with the value operator VALUE.

Workaround : instead of `WRITE children[ 1 ]->data`, use:

```
DATA(child) = children[ 1 ].
WRITE child->data.
```

Comment: okay thank you, and how i can loop through the hole table to print all elements?

Comment: Want to loop? Use [`LOOP`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abaploop_at_itab.htm).

Comment: sorry that i ask again, i add rows with append, how i would insert column values and how can I access these in this example?

Comment: one doesn't *insert* column, but rather fills row structure with column values, you have the only column named `data` and you are filling it in `APPEND NEW #( data = 'test' ) TO children.` line, the second column of `class1` is deep attribute `children` (int.table). You can access the line of the inner class table by `WRITE child->children[ 1 ]->data.` with the Sandra's example or loop it like `LOOP AT child->children INTO DATA(childe).`

Comment: `WRITE child->children[ 1 ]->data` but this valid only since 7.50 as correctly said Sandra, to recursively open inner classes tables you need auxiliary variable for each nested level as in the example

Answer (score 1):

Let us know the ABAP version of your SAP server. Your code perfectly works fine for ABAP version 7.4 onwards.

For versions less than 7.3 kindly use the following code.

```
  DATA children TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF REF TO class1.
  DATA: child TYPE REF TO class1.
  CREATE OBJECT child EXPORTING data = 'test'.
  append child to children.
  write children[ 1 ]->data.
```

I see the issue could also be with your pointer operator(->) which I feel could be an encoding problem.

Kindly try this

Comment: I use version 7.4

Comment: Try the following code after copying it to notepad @Detlef7able, It might work